# can an android device be in danger on a malicious site?

Tags: security

I accidentally went onto a site via Google images and went off after half a second, (the page had been quarter/half loaded. I accidentally hit the undo button and it opened again, and I closed it again.
Virustotal had 1 scanner, "website security guard" say it was a malware site. Scumware.org listed 10 pages on the site having scrinject.gen b, and or trojan.blackhole.-1.

The page I accidentally visited was not one of the 10.
Is it possible these exploits/malware do anything to an android device? I know malware is prevelant on the app store, but can malicious / possible websites be danger for an android device? I am worried about anything that keylogs or steals info.

I scanned with AvG (Tablet), MBAM mobile, Clean Master, Clean Master Security, Avast and used ES file explorer to manually look around, and havent found anything. Clean master security found not an infection, but a vulnerability, named towelroot. I think this is on alot of devices, (not an infection, just a vulnerability).

I havent seen any notifications, ads, or had any redirects. Should I factory reset in case or is there no need?

Comment: It depends if the malicious targets android devices

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever believe that iOS or android cannot get viruses, they may be LESS susceptible to viruses just to the simple fact that there are significantly less viruses for mobile platforms as opposed to say windows. I strongly advise against going to websites from google images. I have battled for countless hours with other computer viruses that people got from browsing images from google. Try downloading AVG from the play store and running a few scans, I also suggest periodic cleanings with Ccleaner! Best of luck

Comment: I see you tried avg so disregard that information!! But the rest is still of use

Answer (score 0):

in short. Yes.
They are plenty of malware sites out there, targeting android devices.
I recommend [avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) or [bitdefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitdefender.security).

Comment: I should mention the device is not rooted, used chrome and outside market apps were turned off. The scumware report says theres scrinject.gen b. I believe its only for windows, but could the site have downloaded anything for the 1 second I was on it?

Comment: A lot of "anti-virus" apps are really scamware them self.
If your device is not rooted I wouldn't be to worind about it

Comment: Should I factory wipe? Would that remove any possibility of there being malware? Or is that overkill? I dont see any pop ups or anything happening or find files associated with the malware "scrinject". I checked macafees site to see what files it creates and cant find any.

Comment: If the virus actually got in on a nonrooted device, then I must have access to a zero-day exploit and those are very very rare, and factory reset will not help (it would be in system partition)
but I really don't think this is the case, factory reset is an overkill on my opinion

Comment: Well im positive its not rooted. I used ES file explorer to view my files in the root directory (which is an app from the store). Iwas able to use it fine and search through the root folder. Does this mean im rooted? I used the root checker app and it says my device does not have proper root acess. Just checking to make sure. Im sure the only way to root is by using pc software? (Which ive never used.

Comment: try to access /data/data
If you can view it, you are rooted.

Comment: I can view /data, nothing inside using ES file explorer.